# Price increase in sql table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

my table like this

```
Date        F.Type  L.Price  H.Price  increase
04/11/2019  apple   10        30        10
04/11/2019  banana   2        6        2
05/11/2019  apple    20       60        20
05/11/2019  grape   50        100       25
```

my requirement

```
Date        F.Type    Price
04/11/2019  apple     10
04/11/2019  apple     20
04/11/2019  apple     30   (L.Price+increase upto H.Price)
04/11/2019  banana    2
04/11/2019  banana    4
04/11/2019  banana    6   (L.Price+increase upto H.Price)
05/11/2019  apple    20
05/11/2019  apple    40
05/11/2019  apple    60   (L.Price+increase upto H.Price)
05/11/2019  grape    50 
05/11/2019  grape    75 
05/11/2019  grape    100  (L.Price+increase upto H.Price)
```

Comment: You would need (I think) either a recursive CTE for this, or you would have to write a stored procedure.  Normal SQL reporting can't easily do what you need.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using MSSQL, you can try this solution with recursive CTE-

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0b7685090efa925e3e4c540129ce75e8)

```
WITH your_table(Date,F_Type,L_Price,H_Price,increase)
AS
(
SELECT '04/11/2019','apple',50,100,10 
UNION ALL SELECT '04/11/2019','banana',2,6,2 
UNION ALL SELECT '05/11/2019','apple',20,60,10 
UNION ALL SELECT '05/11/2019','grape',50,100,25
)

,CTE2 AS (
    SELECT 
    A.Date AD,
    A.F_Type FT,
    A.L_Price,
    A.L_Price inc,
    A.H_Price,
    A.increase
    FROM your_table A

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
    B.AD,
    B.FT ,
    B.L_Price,
    B.inc + B.increase increase, 
    B.H_Price,
    B.increase
    FROM CTE2 B
    WHERE inc < B.H_Price
    AND AD = B.AD AND FT = B.FT
)

SELECT AD AS Date, FT AS F_Type, inc AS Price 
FROM CTE2
ORDER BY 1,2,3
```

Comment: @Venkat, if performance of this approach is OK for you, then go with it. Another approach would be to use a table of numbers plus `CROSS APPLY` to generate needed rows.

Comment: it is helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

As you input doesn't go more that 1 step increase, so just try `UNION`

Try This

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT Date, F.Type, L.Price As Price From table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Date, F.Type, F.Price As Price From table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Date, F.Type, F.Price - L.Price As Price From table
)T ORDER BY Date,Price
```

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=42a9ba55ff480d1aa1b63aa17bc48ffa)**

Comment: upto two steps it is ok but some times it needs more